# keeping track of multiple related input boxes using spring mvc

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

we have a list of domain objects needing to be edited on an html page.  For example, the command & domain objects:

```
class MyCommand {
    List<Person> persons;
}

class Person {
    String fname;
    String lname;
}
```

Then, the HTML I *expect* to have the Spring MVC tag libraries generate is like this:

```
<form>
   <input name="persons[0].fname">&nbsp;<input name="persons[0].lname"><br/>
   <input name="persons[1].fname">&nbsp;<input name="persons[1].lname"><br/>
   <input name="persons[2].fname">&nbsp;<input name="persons[2].lname"><br/>
   ...
   <input name="persons[n].fname">&nbsp;<input name="persons[n].lname"><br/>
</form>
```

But can't see how to express this using the Spring Form Tag Libraries (using Spring 2.5.6.). I want to use the tag libraries so that it takes care of binding existing values to the tags for editing (when they're there).

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to simply have the Spring Form Tags generate the whole list based on the collection (it will do this for the options in a select box, but that's the only collection-based expansion I'm aware of).  However, you can still use the Spring Form Tags within a loop like so:

```
<c:forEach var="person" varStatus="loopStatus" items="myCommand.persons">
   <form:input path="persons[${loopStatus.index}].fname" />&nbsp;<form:input path="persons[${loopStatus.index}].lname" /><br />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: @eqbridges, you sure its working??? I am getting like "Invalid property 'persons[0]' of bean class MyClass.Bean property 'persons[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method:"

Comment: @Jaikrat -- this code assumes that the bean that you're binding the form to has a property "persons" that is a collection that can be assigned to using `persons[0]` and `persons[1]` and so forth -- a `list`, for example. Your error suggests that this isn't the case in your bean. Do you have a `persons` property? If so, what is it?

Comment: Hey @JacobMattison. Thanks for replying. I get that. My class structure is not exactly same as the above one. Its more little complicated. Its like, I have one class PayForm, inside it I have one attribute of type Issuer, Inside Issuer I have one List of AddressBean and this AddressBean is having one var of type Amount which have one var amount. So this addressBean's list I have 2 display and fetch the data later from on input box( amount).Right now I can't post the code of what I tried because I am at home.But if you get it then please help me. I have to show/fetch d same input box (amount).

Comment: Hmm, OK... it's hard to respond without seeing the code (and you may want to ask a new question, which you can certainly post a link to here) but... in general, if you're binding to a property of a property of something in a collection, you may need to do something like ` path="issuer.addresses[${loopStatus.index}].amount,whatever"` -- that is, you are looping through whatever level in the object path has the collection.  This also does require that getter and setter methods exist at each level.

Comment: Yes Thanks. Its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508868/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-one-tpye-and-show-fetch-data-from-input-boxout-of-that