# How to iterate a List of one tpye and show/fetch data from input box(out of that list) in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have one Class PaymentForm, inside it I have one variable of type Issuer. Inside Issuer there is one var addressList of type Address, which have three vars addrId, addressLine1 and payment. The payment is of type Payment and at last there is one var in Payment, paymentAmt of type int.

So I have to iterate the List (addressList) in jsp. There is two input boxes and one label in jsp which is mapped to addrId and addressLine of Address and payment of Payment. which is somewhere deep down in the List.

What I have tried so far

1) "**payForm**" is the commandName declared at the form level, **counter** is the var declared at the top of the page in scripplet.

```
<c:forEach var="pointer" varStatus="loopStatus" items="payForm.issuer.addressList">
    <DIV style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b><%=counter++%>)</b>
            </td>
            <td><form:input style="display:none;" path="issuer.addressList[${loopStatus.index}].addrID"/> </td>
            <td><c:out value="${pointer.addressLine}"/></td>                                                    
            <td><form:input path="issuer.addressList[${loopStatus.index}].payment.paymentAmt" size="17" maxlength="12"/></td>
        </tr>
    </DIV>
</c:forEach>
```

Error With this :-

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'addressLine'.*

2)

```
<td><c:out value="${issuer.addressList[${loopStatus.index}].addressLine}"/> </td>
```

Error With this is:-

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/invoice.jsp(162,17) "${issuer.addressList[${loopStatus.index}].addressLine}" contains invalid expression(s): {1}*

3)

```
<td><c:out value="${payForm.issuer.addressList[${loopStatus.index}].addressLine}"/></td>
```

Error With this:-

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/invoice.jsp(162,17) "${payForm.issuer.addressList[${loopStatus.index}].addressLine}" contains invalid expression(s): {1}*

No issue with first and third field. Only the middle one is creating problem here.

**It started working With below code**

```
<td><c:out value="${payForm.issuer.addressList[0].addrID}"/></td>
```

But its harcode. How to get the value 0,1,2,3... using "**loopStatus**" var of c:if

Comment: What is the structure of `payForm`.

Comment: Its a model object of PayForm class. Like model.addObject("payForm", newPayForm()); PayForm is a class described above.

Comment: i hope you have must learned spelling skills in early class... :) ..  type*

Comment: Can you check that it has proper getter method for `addressLine` field.

Comment: `Inside Issuer there is one var addressList of type Address`, then why are using `for` loop? It is iterating over what?

Comment: I think, thats not required becuase its saying String do not have peroperty addressLine. Its not saying my class Address do not have set/get of type addresesLine. Though there is a var addresesLine and its set/get.

Comment: addressList  is a List of type Address.

Comment: Can you show us code of the structure of Address class.

Comment: Class Address{
 int addrID = 0;
 String addressLine = "";
 Payment payment = null;
//setter/getter of all these vars
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74701/discussion-between-naman-gala-and-jaikrat).

Comment: Did your problem get solve?

Comment: No, I just tried with hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

Its working with below code

```
<td><c:out value="${payForm.issuer.addressList[loopStatus.index].addrID}"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your answer there are 3 solutions

**Approach 1:** Which you have stated in your answer.

```
<td><c:out value="${payForm.issuer.addressList[loopStatus.index].addrID}"/></td>
```

---

**Approach 2:**

```
<td><c:out value="issuer.addressList[${loopStatus.index}].addrID"/></td>
```

---

**Approach 3:** Not advisable because of escape character. This will put doors open to [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

```
<td>${payForm.issuer.addressList[loopStatus.index].addrID}</td>
```

---

*But still I can't find why below approach is not working.* As it is working in my pages.

```
<td><c:out value="${pointer.addressLine}"/></td>
```

I am not sure, but does this code gives you the output?

```
<td><c:out value="${pointer.addrID}"/></td>
```

Comment: This <td><c:out value="${pointer.addrID}"/></td> does not give me too. Same like <td><c:out value="${pointer.addressLine}"/></td>.